# Given k words, determine words equality in constant time

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have encountered this question while studying for algorithms test:

Given a set of k words (strings), with a total character count of n, (meaning the sum of all words lengths are n), perform some sort of manipulation on the words in O(n) time, such that whenever 2 words are being compared, return answer (whether they are identical or not) in O(1) time.

It's an interesting question but I could not find any direction to deal with it...

Comment: Store all the words in an array, and then if you want the job to be get done in constant time, I think you will have to specify the words by the indices of array. If that is fine then you just need hashed values of all words and you are done.

Comment: Hash table will give me an average time complexity of O(1) but in the worst case O(n)
Not good enogh...

Answer (score 0):

Construct a trie of all of the words, and for each word store the index of its last character in the array.  This is a `O(n)` operation.

Given two words, they are the same if and only if the index of their last character is the same.